# Debian - command fatlabel is missing but package dosfstools that contains the command is already installed

Tags: linux, terminal, package-management, command, man

I want to change the volume label of a FAT usb with `fatlabel` but when I try to run the command in terminal it does not recognize it.

```
root@debian:/home/a# fatlabel --help
bash: fatlabel: command not found
```

So I tried installing `dosfstools` which is the package that contains `fatlabel`. However it is already installed.

```
root@debian:/home/a# apt-get install dosfstools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
dosfstools is already the newest version (4.2-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Both `man fatlabel` and the online manpage https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/dosfstools/fatlabel.8.en.html clearly state that `fatlabel` is the right name to use to invoke the command. How can I restore the command?

Answer (score 1):

The command is in `/sbin`, so presumably your `PATH` doesn’t include that directory (which would happen if you changed to `root` using `su` for example).

The quick fix is to give its full path:

```
/sbin/fatlabel --help
```

You can find where a given package’s commands are installed using `dpkg -L`:

```
dpkg -L dosfstools | grep bin/
```